# How to add a toolbar to a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

The only way I've ever been able to get a toolbar to work is when the view/table view is embedded in a navigation controller. Presumably, there are other ways to use a toolbar, even placing them at the top of the scene,  as done here:
[image]

(That article is from September 2012 using the iOS 6 SDK, so it isn't horribly out of date or anything.)

Makes me feel pretty stupid, but I cannot for the life of me get a toolbar to drop onto a view in the storyboard.

Comment: Which item do you drag from the objects library?

Comment: "Toolbar", which I assume means UIToolbar.

Comment: I just tried and did add a lot of them... To which UIView subclass (also the view controller) are you trying to add it?

Comment: Well, I came in this morning, fired up the same project, and sure enough--that toolbar plopped right onto the view. I can't for the life of me tell what I'm doing different. Must have been yesterday's lack of coffee. Anyway, thanks for the help, @Moxy. I appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you had zoomed out. I think you can't add views when the storyboard is zoomed out

Comment: There's an idea. I'll keep that in mind.